# Android: How to create custom UI of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I am trying to create custom TextInputLayout. How can I create below custom TextInputLayout?

[image]

Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

Comment: have you tried styling https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/

Comment: Hi @Raghunandan thanks for the reply. I have tried styling with Material Components styles but not able to make bottom-left and bottom-right corner to of 'round shape'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) provided by the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/...."    
       app:boxStrokeColor="@color/..."
       android:hint="..."
       ..>

         <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
           ../>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

About the **rounded corners**:

**The default behaviour** for the `FilledBox` `(Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox`) is a rounded box on the top corners (`4dp`) and a rectangular box on the bottom (`0dp`) as you can see in the image above.
If you would like a rounded box, I suggest you using the `OutlinedBox` style:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    ..>
```

The resul is:

[image]

Otherwise you can force a workaround like this (I don't like it since it breaks the material guideline):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout       
app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/Rounded_ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
            app:boxStrokeColor="yourActivityBackgroundColor"
            ..>
```

where the `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute changes the shape of the bottom corners:

```
  <style name="Rounded_ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">@dimen/mtrl_shape_corner_size_small_component</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">@dimen/mtrl_shape_corner_size_small_component</item>
  </style>
```

where `mtrl_shape_corner_size_small_component=4dp`

[image]

Comment: Hi @Gabriele Mariotti thanks for the quick reply. Can you please guide me to make bottom-left and bottom-right corner to of 'round' shape.

Comment: @abhishekkumargupta the best way in this case is to use the `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` style. Using the default (`Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox`) you can achieve it but you can have some issue with the line in the bottom.

Comment: With FilledBox style, I am able to make rounded corners with app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd and  app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart but as you have mentioned in the comment, currently struggling with the line in the bottom.

Comment: @abhishekkumargupta I suggest you using a different design (standard filled or standard outlined). There is a workaround but I don't like this solution. You can add `app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"`and `app:boxStrokeColor="yourActivityBackgroudColor"`. In this way the line in the bottom is not visible.

Comment: @abhishekkumargupta I've just updated the answer with both examples.

Answer (score 0):

try as below

```
  <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Main2Activity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#d4d4d4"
        android:weightSum="1">

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="fullname"

          android:background="#FFFFFF"
          android:layout_margin="10dp"
          android:padding="10dp"
          >
          <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Aalina Rodgers"
              android:padding="10dp"/>
      </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="fullname"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Aalina Rodgers"
                android:padding="10dp"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="fullname"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Aalina Rodgers"
                android:padding="10dp"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is not correct. Don't use `android:background` in the `TextInputLayout`. Use  `boxBackgroundColor`.

Comment: but it is not working i tried in my xml in not shows any color @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: It works. Check also the [doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#filled-box-default)